# socket.io definition file for TypeScript

Tags: socket.io, typescript

I want to create a node.js server app using socket.io and write it with TypeScript. Is there currently a definition file for socket.io floating around, or am I going to have to work with a `declare var socketio: any` for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using this one

https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions/blob/master/socket.io.d.ts

which hasn't failed me yet (though I haven't tried everything yet).

Edit: This was also just suggested as an addition to the wonderful [DefinitelyTyped project](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)

https://github.com/worr/DefinitelyTyped/commit/0be80b5a26e1a4fb9734e935bf6dff872de7182c